# Loading Hugging face model is taking too much memory

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am trying to load a large Hugging face model with code like below:

```
model_from_disc = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(path_to_model)
tokenizer_from_disc = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_model)
generator = pipeline("text-generation", model=model_from_disc, tokenizer=tokenizer_from_disc)
```

The program is quickly crashing **after the first line** because it is running out of memory. Is there a way to chunk the model as I am loading it, so that the program doesn't crash?

---

**EDIT**

See cronoik's answer for accepted solution, but here are the relevant pages on Hugging Face's documentation:

**Sharded Checkpoints:** [https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/big_models#sharded-checkpoints:~:text=in%20the%20future.-,Sharded%20checkpoints,-Since%20version%204.18.0](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/big_models#sharded-checkpoints:%7E:text=in%20the%20future.-,Sharded%20checkpoints,-Since%20version%204.18.0)

**Large Model Loading:** [https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#:~:text=the%20weights%20instead.-,Large%20model%20loading,-In%20Transformers%204.20.0](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#:%7E:text=the%20weights%20instead.-,Large%20model%20loading,-In%20Transformers%204.20.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to load it with [low_cpu_mem_usage](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#large-model-loading):

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model_from_disc = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(path_to_model, low_cpu_mem_usage=True)
```

Please note that `low_cpu_mem_usage` requires:
Accelerate >= 0.9.0 and PyTorch >= 1.9.0.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you for the response. I also learned that you can shard when saving the model with something like this: model.save_pretrained(path_to_model, max_shard_size="200MB")

Comment: ^ In fact, I think you might need to set a max_shard_size for low_cpu_mem_usage to do anything, but I am not totally sure

Comment: `max_shard_size` is independent of `low_cpu_mem_usage`.