# How to skip weights init when loading pretrained transformers model?

Tags: python, pytorch, initialization, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I need to find out how to load a pretrained transformer model without initializing weights in the beginning (to save time and memory)?

1. I saw this code example, but this is not elegant:

   ```
   saved_inits = torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_, 
       torch.nn.init.uniform_, 
       torch.nn.init.normal_  # preserving
   torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_ = skip
   torch.nn.init.uniform_ = skip
   torch.nn.init.normal_ = skip

   model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=args.model_path)

   torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_, 
       torch.nn.init.uniform_, 
       torch.nn.init.normal_ = saved_inits  # restoring
   ```
2. for `nn.module` subclasses there is `torch.nn.utils.skip_init`, but it won't work with `AutoModelForCausalLM`

Quest: find a way to skip weights initialization in `AutoModelForCausalLM` (or any similar transformers class)  either using some standard wrapper or parameter.

Comment: You can save memory with [low_cpu_mem_usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726174/6664872). I don't think it will save (much) time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was suggested in the comment by cronoik:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model_name_or_path=args.model_path,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True
    )
```

I tested it with Llama 30B and found 3x acceleration in loading time, though no gain in memory use.