# How to run a NLP+Transformers LLM on low memory GPUs?

Tags: python, nlp, gpu, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to load an AI pre-trained model, from intel on hugging face, I have used Colab its resources exceeded, used Kaggle resources increased, used paperspace, which showing me an error:

```
The kernel for Text_Generation.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

this is the model load script:

```
import transformers


model_name = 'Intel/neural-chat-7b-v3-1'
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def generate_response(system_input, user_input):

    # Format the input using the provided template
    prompt = f"### System:\n{system_input}\n### User:\n{user_input}\n### Assistant:\n"

    # Tokenize and encode the prompt
    inputs = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt", add_special_tokens=False)

    # Generate a response
    outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length=1000, num_return_sequences=1)
    response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    # Extract only the assistant's response
    return response.split("### Assistant:\n")[-1]


# Example usage
system_input = "You are a math expert assistant. Your mission is to help users understand and solve various math problems. You should provide step-by-step solutions, explain reasonings and give the correct answer."
user_input = "calculate 100 + 520 + 60"
response = generate_response(system_input, user_input)
print(response)

# expected response
"""
To calculate the sum of 100, 520, and 60, we will follow these steps:

1. Add the first two numbers: 100 + 520
2. Add the result from step 1 to the third number: (100 + 520) + 60

Step 1: Add 100 and 520
100 + 520 = 620

Step 2: Add the result from step 1 to the third number (60)
(620) + 60 = 680

So, the sum of 100, 520, and 60 is 680.
"""
```

My purpose is to load this pretrained model, I have done some research on my end I have find some solutions but not working with me,

> download packages using cuda instead of pip

Comment: Please specify low memory (4 GB, 8 GB, 16 GB?). One thing you could definitively try is [low_cpu_mem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726174/6664872).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [model quantization](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/quantization) as this is one of the approaches which specifically addresses this type of problem, of loading a large model for inference.

[TheBloke](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke) has provided a quantized version of this model which is available here: [neural-chat-7B-v3-1-AWQ](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/neural-chat-7B-v3-1-AWQ). To use this, you'll need to use AutoAWQ, and as per Hugging Face [in this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HzZH89yAXJaZgwJDhQj9LqSBux932BvY#scrollTo=mRwsuEtsZYrs), for Colab you need to install an earlier version given Colab's CUDA version.

You should also make sure your model is using GPU, not CPU, by adding `.cuda()` to the input tensor after it is generated:

```py
!pip install -q transformers accelerate
!pip install -q -U https://github.com/casper-hansen/AutoAWQ/releases/download/v0.1.6/autoawq-0.1.6+cu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl

import torch
from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_name = 'TheBloke/neural-chat-7B-v3-1-AWQ'
### Use AutoAWQ and from quantized instead of transformers here
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_quantized(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def generate_response(system_input, user_input):

    # Format the input using the provided template
    prompt = f"### System:\n{system_input}\n### User:\n{user_input}\n### Assistant:\n"

    ### ADD .cuda()
    inputs = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt", add_special_tokens=False).cuda()

    # Generate a response
    outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length=1000, num_return_sequences=1)
    response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    # Extract only the assistant's response
    return response.split("### Assistant:\n")[-1]
```