# Loading a pretrained model is not working, what could be the issue?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, peft

I have fine-tuned a LLM (mistral) using huggingface AutoTrain. The model params and checkpoints have been saved on a huggingface model repository that can be found here:

https://huggingface.co/Layla321/llm_finetuning-0

I am trying to load the model into google colab so that I can test it and utilize it, I am using the following code:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model_path = "Layla321/llm_finetuning-0"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_path,
    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype='auto'
).eval()


messages = [
    {"role": "user", "content": "hi"}
]

input_ids = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(conversation=messages, tokenize=True, add_generation_prompt=True, return_tensors='pt')
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids.to('cuda'))
response = tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0][input_ids.shape[1]:], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(response)
```

But unfortunately, it gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'TrainingArguments' object has no attribute 'values'

I have no idea what might be causing this issue, I have the most updated transformer library and in addition, I also tried to clear the cache, but the error remains.

Comment: The code you posted isn't the one that generated the error. Please also avoid posting screenshots.

Comment: apologies for that, I was trying a different method in loading the model with pipeline, but it was also giving me a similar error. I removed the screenshot for your preference

Comment: It looks like the model you have trained was trained with `peft` and is based on `mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1`. You can't load a `peft` model directly with a class from transformers. You can either load it with peft or merge the weights back. Refer to this answer for further information: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77596556/6664872).

Comment: Thank you for your response, that makes sense. I am using the AutoPeftModel to load the model, however, it requires high RAM storage, above 29 GB. My main goal of using AutoTrain was to overcome the issue of limited computational resources. But unfortunately, it seems that I cannot escape from renting a cloud-based GPU

Comment: A big model is still a big model, even with AutoTrain. Depending on your requirements you could try [quantization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594086/how-to-run-a-nlptransformers-llm-on-low-memory-gpus), but that always affects the performance.